# Hiding a class with onsubmit() without preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html

The submit button is refreshing the page, which leads to showing elements, I don't want to be shown.

I tried having a preventDefault() function but then it wouldn't submit the form. 
I tried it without but if I do so, the form would submit but the elements are still shown.

```
$(".signupbtn").click(function(e){
    console.log("Sign up clicked");
    document.getElementsByClassName("huhu")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("afterForm")[0].style.display = "block";
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Succes")
});


<!-- the output from the form -->
<div class="afterForm" >
    <h3 id="output"/>
</div>

<!-- the submiting -->

  <form class="modal-content" id="myForm" onsubmit="readForm()">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 >Order</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to receive your meal. Required fields: *</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="email"><b>Email*</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="zyxzyx@domain.com" name="email" value="" required>

      <label for="adr1"><b>Adress* (Housenumber, Street, City)</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="555, Zxy blvd, San zxy" name="adr1" value="" required>
      <label for="adr2"><b>Adress* (ZIP, State)</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="00000, ZY" name="adr2" value="" required>
      <p>By pressing "Order" you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" >Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>


<!-- the ordering -->

<div class="huhu">
    <h1 class="ord">Select your order:</h1>
    <input onclick="firstIcon()" id="fIcon" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kw6l23hm37kzqq8/sushi.png" />
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;vertical-align:middle" class="button">
        <span>Next Step </span>
    </button>
</div>


button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

button:hover {
  opacity:1;
}

.signupbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

I except the class "huhu" to vanish and the class "afterForm" to show after the order button is clicked. If don't fill in the form, click Order and then cancel, the elements hide but don't show.

Is there an other solution than `preventDefault()` or is the solution easier than I thought?

Comment: Do you want to submit the form without refresh the page?

Comment: Yes I want to submit it, so I can retrieve the data in JS but don't want to refresh it because it would show everything again

Comment: You should use ajax. When a user clicks on "submit" button, u need to get the user input and then create ajax call to server-side, after that get the result from the server, finally update the related part of the web page.